# ios - tableView reloadData is not working

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I have problem with my `tableView`, which gets data from `webServices`. The `tableView` already get data returned by web service successfully: `videosArray = (_NSArrayM *) @"32 objects"`
but everytime I try to reloadData, there seems to be a forever loop and I got this error `"thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=1 , address=0x2000000c)"` at the line `[self.videosTableView reloadData].` 
And even if I don't get data from Web service at all, it still crashes with weird error `"-[__NSArrayI numberOfSectionsInTableView:]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e2dd90", I always return 1 formethod `numberOfSectionsInTableView`. By the way, I create new file for `tableview datasource` and `delegate` method, here is method for setting delegate and `datasource` for `tableview`:

```
- (id)initWithTableView:(DTVideoTableView *)tblViewP viewController:(UIViewController*)vc andUrlString:(NSString*)url{
self = [super init];
if (self) {

    self.messageTitleString = @"Loading...";
    self.videosTableView = (DTVideoTableView *)tblViewP;
    self.viewController = vc;
    NSLog(@"%@", url);
    self.urlString = url;
    self.videosTableView.videosArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self.videosTableView.videosArray addVideosArrayFromUserURL:url];

    tblViewP.delegate = self;
    tblViewP.dataSource = self;

    [self addRefreshController];
    userRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#\\w+" options:0 error:nil];

    UIFont *fontNumber;
    if(IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_7){
        fontNumber =  [UIFont fontWithName:@"avenir-heavy" size:14];
    }
    else{
        fontNumber =  [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    }

    fullAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                      fontNumber, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
    [self.videosTableView reloadData];
}
return self;
```

}

Here is some of table View datasource methods, they are called only once:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [self.videosTableView.videosArray count];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}
```

Could you guys tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thank you !!

Comment: how about your cellForRow method?

Comment: Why do you have calls to `self.self`?

Comment: I also have it in the file, by the way I get this error thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=1 , address=0x2000000c) !! Thanks for replying !!

Comment: I updated my code, it was just mistake.

Comment: if there is no data from web service then you should not call tableview. check the condition if(self.videosTableView.videosArray.count>0) then call tableview. this will fix the issue.

Comment: I actually checked and there is data there. I am wondering why I get "thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=1 , address=0x2000000c)". How do I check where I do wrong with this error?

Comment: in which line this is coming .

Comment: Can you paste the information in array and cell configure code

Comment: I updated the my problem, cellForRowAtIndexPath is only call once before there is data, and reloadData take an forever loop so I guess I don't need to post it here, it is fine, I worked with it before !!

Comment: Make sure you get the data before re-loading the table view.

Answer (score 0):

Okei guys, I knew what I was doing wrong. My DTVideoCellDataSource was freed so my tableView could not use it anymore. I fixed it. Thank you !!